# How to generate source files and compile them with gradle

Tags: groovy, build, gradle

I have a gradle build script similar to:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

task genSources << {
  // here I generate some java files
}

// making sure that source files are generated
// before compilation
compileJava.dependsOn(genSources)
```

How can I make the files generated in `genSources` compile along with files in `src/main/java` during `compileJava`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may try adding the path to the generated sources like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '<path to generatedJava>'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eg sourceSets.main.java.srcDir '<path to generatedJava>'

Comment: You can also add multiples via `srcDirs 'build/generated-src/java', 'src/main/java'`

Comment: I found this helped me get the generated files **compiled** OK from a `generated/java/` location.  But for some reason the task to generate the JAXB classes from XSD files does NOT fire even when it is a dependency of the compile in **genSources**.    I still need to manually enter:  `gradle xjc` separate, and before I Build.  _Any ideas?_