# Compile code with generated source by annotation processor on Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, annotations, javac, annotation-processing

I extended the AbstractProcessor to create an annotation processor to generate a class in Java and it works fine.

The first issue is: the class only is generated for the **second time I run** `./gradlew build`. The first time I run it, the build folder is generated, but the annotations generated code not.

The second issue (that my be related to the first one) **Gradle won't compile if I have some code that is dependent of the generated class. It throws:**

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
/src/main/java/me/fouyer/Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
```

My `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'me.fouyer'
version = '1.0.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor('me.fouyer:annotation:1.0.0')
}
```

I created a repository with a minimal, reproducible example where I have the annotation, the annotation processor and a Person class that uses the annotation. [GitHub](https://github.com/joaofouyer/annotation-mre)

I already tried:

- Using Google's Auto Service.
- Removing Google's Auto Service and creating `src/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` manually.
- Running on terminal or by IntelliJ's interface
- [Gradle can not compile the code with the generated sources by annotationProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025140/gradle-can-not-compile-the-code-with-the-generated-sources-by-annotationprocesso) He had the same issue, but in his case the error was on generating the file. But I tried to copy his `build.gradle` but the task `preProcessAnnotation` is a little bit confusing for me on what it does and how could I change it for my scenario.
- [Adding the path to the generated sources using SourceSets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5028796)